# Keycloak gives "Username or password is wrong" error after pressed "unlink users" button

Tags: spring-boot, ldap, keycloak

I'm using a standalone Keycloak 4.5.0 version on the Centos for providing secure-login with LDAP  for a web application.

It was working successfully but when somebody After pressing the "unlink users" button on the Keycloak Admin Panel > User federation > LDAP, anybody can not log in with the LDAP username and password because it gives that "Username or password is wrong" error.

I tried to pressing "Sychronize All Users" button but there is no changing.
So i restarted to keycloak appication from server but the problem was not change.

I checked the server logs of keycloak and it gives that :

```
11:22:51,152 ERROR [org.keycloak.events.EventBuilder] (default task-1) Event listener 'user' registered, but provider not found .
```

so please help me for this login problem and give info about the unlink users button.

thx for responses.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for keycloak to get the password from ldap. After the unlink process the password can't be checked anymore and the login would fail. You have to set the "password reset action" for the users to let them specify a new one.

An interesting approach for migrating users can be found here: [Migrate to Keycloak with Zero Downtime](https://medium.com/@olgaatsmartling/migrate-to-keycloak-with-zero-downtime-74d4997d91ad)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it's possible to [re-link the users manually via the database](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10490#discussioncomment-2427989):

1. Go to `COMPONENT` table, and find the configuration name of your LDAP
   configuration in User Federation. Copy the ID
2. Go to your `USER_ENTITY` table and query the account you want to
   restore
3. On the `FEDERATION_LINK` column of the account data, paste the
   COMPONENT id
4. Verify by hitting the "Synchronized all user" button in your User
   Federation configuration page

Sample query to Find Federation ID from `COMPONENT` table based on `REALM_ID` with query: `SELECT id FROM COMPONENT WHERE NAME = '<mapper-ldap-name>' AND REALM_ID = '<realm-name>';`.

Sample query to update federation_link column in `USER_ENTITY` based on `REALM_ID` with query:
`UPDATE USER_ENTITY SET FEDERATION_LINK = '<federation-id>' WHERE REALM_ID = '<realm-name>';`

Answer (score 0):

We solved it by deleting all users except admin using a shell script like this and then "Synchronize all Users". You could also delete them through UI if you still have admin access.

```
kcadm=/opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh
$kcadm config credentials --server http://localhost:8080/auth --realm master --user admin
for x in $($kcadm get users -r myrealm|jq -r '.[].id'); do $kcadm delete users/$x -r myrealm; done
```